# Filtering with a multi-select menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu, filtering, vuejs3

So I have a select menu that lets the user select multiple options. the selected options correspond to `actorModel`.
Then I have an object array and I wish to filter it according to the selected options.
If the user selected option A and B , then it will return two objects from `actorDocs`.
The one that has a label value 'A' and the one that has the label value 'B'.
If no option is selected (`actorModel` is null) then it will return all objects from `actorDocs`.

The problem I am encountering in this code is that it only works if the user selects one option.
If the user selects more than one, then I tink it is trying to locate an object that has several labels instead of several objects with each label.

Any help is more than welcome

```
const actorModel = ref({ 0:'label1', 1:'label2', 3:'label3'})
const actorDocs = ref([{'label':'label1'},{'label':'label2'},{'label':'label3'},{'label':'label4'}])

const actorListTest2 = computed(() => {
    if (actorModel.value == null){var ttt = actorDocs.value} 
    else { 

      var ttt = actorDocs.value.filter(obj => {
        return (
         (!actorModel.value.length || obj.label.includes(actorModel.value) )
       ) })}
    lenActordata.value = ttt.length
    return ttt
    });
```

Comment: I gave your suggestion a try and the result remained the same @MWO

Comment: what if you write your filter like this `var ttt = actorDocs.filter(obj => {
        if(!Object.keys(actorModel.value).length ||  Object.values(actorModel.value).includes(obj.label)) return obj
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
const actorModel = {0:'label1', 1:'label3'}
const actorDocs = [{'label':'label1'}, {'label':'label2'}, {'label':'label3'}, {'label':'label4'}]

const actorListTest2 = () => {
  if (actorModel == null){
    return actorDocs
  } else { 
    return actorDocs.filter(obj => [...Object.values(actorModel)].includes(obj.label))
  }
};
console.log(actorListTest2())
```